# why is the sort function not sorting a struct?

Tags: c

I have the `pair` struct below which contains two variables:

```
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;
```

And I am trying to sort them according to the array `pair_strength` which is in the same length. However, while the sorting function seems fine, the ordering of the `pair` struct is not changing at all. Below is the sort function:

```
int pair_strength[] = {1, 5, 2, 4, 3};
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (pair_strength[j] < pair_strength[j+1])
            {
                int temp_w = pairs[j].winner;
                int temp_l = pairs[j].loser;
                pairs[j].winner = pairs[j+1].winner;
                pairs[j].loser = pairs[j+1].loser;
                pairs[j+1].winner = temp_w;
                pairs[j+1].loser = temp_l;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Therefore, given that 5 is the second element in `pair_strength` and is the biggest number, I want to move the second elements in both variables ( `winner` and `loser`) in `pair` struct to the first and so on

Comment: `pair_strength` never changes; shouldn't they move with the elements they describe the strength of?

Comment: You're not actually sorting the very data you're comparing. That will *not* work. And fyi, C supports structured assignment. I.e. `pair tmp = pairs[j];` etc..

Comment: Is `pairs[j].winner` initialized before you call the function?

Comment: you need to sort `pair_strength` as you go otherwise it wont work: e.g. on the first pass you swap `pairs[1]` and `pairs[2]` because `pair_strength[1] < pair_strength[2]` and on the 2nd pass you swap back to the original position because `pair_strength` is unchaged.

Comment: Strongly recommend for you: pen and paper, stepping though your debugger and talking to your rubber duck

Comment: Aside: Use `pair t = pairs[j]; pairs[j] = pairs[j+1]; pairs[j+1] = t;` to swap.

Comment: `int pair_strength = [1, 5, 2, 4, 3];` is a syntax error; please post real code in future

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your help. Below is updated function:

```
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (pair_strength[j] < pair_strength[j+1])
            {
                pair t = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j+1];
                pairs[j+1] = t;
                int t2 = pair_strength[j];
                pair_strength[j] = pair_strength[j+1];
                pair_strength[j+1] = t2;
            }
        }
    }

}
```